# angular-moment-picker is already opened on load and when selecting date it doesn't close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I'm using this date picker for angular https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker

when the page loads, the picker is already opened at the bottom, and when I click on the input, it shows the picker at the top. when selecting a date it doesn't close after that.

```
<input type="text"
              moment-picker="user.date"
              format="YYYY/MM/DD" 
              ng-model="user.date"/>
```

I've already used this picker before in a different project and it was great.
I tried to reproduce this behavior in a different project but I couldn't. Could it be a conflict issue with moment or another library?

These are the other libraries I'm using:

```
"angular": "angularjs#^1.5.8",
"angular-route": "1.5.8",
"angular-sanitize": "1.5.5",
"swagger-js": "2.1.14",
"alertify.js": "alertifyjs#^1.0.10",
"angular-cookies": "1.5.8",
"angular-paging": "2.2.1",
"ng-table": "0.8.3",
"lodash": "4.16.4",
"ng-file-upload": "12.2.12",
"ngInfiniteScroll": "1.3.0",
"select2": "3.4.5",
"textAngular": "1.5.1",
"angularjs-slider": "5.5.1",
"angular-ui-calendar": "1.0.2",
"font-awesome": "4.6.3",
"angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "1.0.1",
"angular-validation": "1.4.2",
"raven-js": "3.7.0",
"keen-js": "3.4.1",
"angular-keenio": "0.2.0",
"angular-translate": "2.12.1",
"moment-timezone": "0.5.5",
"moment": "2.15.1",
"jquery": "3.1.1",
"fullcalendar": "3.0.1",
"angularjs-datetime-picker": "0.1.20",
"angular-moment": "^1.0.0",
"angular-ui-select": "^0.19.4",
"angular-ui-select3": "ui-select#*",
"pubnub": "^4.3.2",
"pubnub-angular": "^4.0.2",
"angular-moment-picker": "moment-picker#^0.8.4"
```